# convert UITableViewController to UIViewController in xcode 4.2

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview, xcode4.2

I need to convert uitableviewcontroller to uiviewcontroller.
It's not a problem in < xcode 4.2.

Normally I just need to change the .h (header file) to :UIViewController
and in IB, remove the connected UITableView outlet and connect the new UIView to view outlet.

In Xcode 4.2, I cannot remove the connected UITableView. It's gray out.
Is it imposible to convert uitableviewcontroller to uiviewcontroller in xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

- Create a new ViewController
- Add a TableView to the root view of new ViewController
- Copy the TableView from the original ViewController
- Select the fresh TableView in your new ViewController
- Paste ViewController

You can then delete the fresh, unused TableView

Answer (score 3):

Create a new ViewController in storyboard.

Click and drag the tableView from UITableViewController to the new viewcontroller.

Now add the four border constraints to the tableview in the viewcontroller(zero at each sides). Now delete the old tableviewcontroller. That's it.

Also change the superclass in the h file to UIViewController. But you will lose all your segues from and to the previous tableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you first created your table class, you told Xcode that it will inherit from `UITableViewController`, so it did its black voodoo magic and connected it to corresponding NIB file. I don't know a good way to fix this other than adding a new class to your project, making it inherit from `UIViewController`, and just copying the code over. Maybe refactoring the names too.